# How can I secure local content by checking a license

Tags: security, unity-game-engine

I have launcher that downloads and launches VR experiences. I also have a server that handles the subscription side of things. Is there a surefire way to protect the content on the local machine until it receives a key or license from the server?

My first thought was to use a session token but that's not going to stop someone from just sniffing the network request and then spoofing it and authorizing their client to play the content. Encryption doesn't seem like it would work as the key would need to be in the client which can then be extracted through various means.

Is there a secure way to decrypt a message sent from a server without having the decryption key exposed in the client?

Comment: To be clear, you want users to be able to download content onto their devices, but not be able to actually use it until you give them a license?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to have the data encrypted on your download server-side with a random key, and then give that key as the license to decrypt the data once the user acquires the license. Since the key is specific to that download and that user, they don't gain much by intercepting the key. Of course, once the data is decrypted, they can do whatever they want with it. There's no way around that without controlling the hardware.